# TableView Cells resizing / Auto layout issue on load. But fixes after second reload? - Graph

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

Does anyone have any experience in why tableView Cells resize? Or why they resize on reload?

I have a cell where I've made a graph from an ImageView. This imageView has a 1:1 aspect ratio, and is centered in the cell on both the X and Y. I then did some math and used the max Bounds of the imageView to set up a second imageView that's a circle in order to plot the data in the graph-imageView.

I also have a didSelectAtRow() function that reloads the cell and hides/unhides labels on the axises. And since the whole row gets reloaded, the plotting in the imageView also gets removed and replotted.

Currently I'm facing a strange issue where the graph doesn't plot the point correctly until the cell has been refreshed a few times. Even though mathematically, it should be positioned correctly.

**How can I fix the changes in the cell and imageView sizes on reload so that it displays correctly on load? Also, Why are the sizes changing?**

Cell on Load:

```
configureCell(): ---
x: Max  238.0
y: Max  238.0
hideDescriptionLabels()
point.silicaX:  3.32
X: xGood
point.aluminaY:  0.45
Y: yGood
x: Max  238.0
y: Max  238.0
xAdjust:  19.833333333333332
graphX:  111.86
yAdjust:  11.9
graphY:  142.79999999999998
aluminaAdjust:  4.5
(xGood, yGood):
x:  238.0
y:  238.0
xRect:  104.36
yRect:  135.29999999999998
imageRect:  (104.36, 135.29999999999998, 15.0, 15.0)
```

[image: Graph on Load]

Cell on first reload:

```
configureCell(): ---
x: Max  238.0
y: Max  238.0
hideDescriptionLabels()
point.silicaX:  3.32
X: xGood
point.aluminaY:  0.45
Y: yGood
x: Max  238.0
y: Max  238.0
xAdjust:  19.833333333333332
graphX:  111.86
yAdjust:  11.9
graphY:  142.79999999999998
aluminaAdjust:  4.5
(xGood, yGood):
x:  238.0
y:  238.0
xRect:  104.36
yRect:  135.29999999999998
imageRect:  (104.36, 135.29999999999998, 15.0, 15.0)
```

[image: Graph on Reload]

Cell on second and all following reloads:

```
configureCell(): ---
x: Max  324.0
y: Max  324.0
hideDescriptionLabels()
point.silicaX:  3.32
X: xGood
point.aluminaY:  0.45
Y: yGood
x: Max  324.0
y: Max  324.0
xAdjust:  27.0
graphX:  152.28
yAdjust:  16.2
graphY:  194.4
aluminaAdjust:  4.5
(xGood, yGood):
x:  324.0
y:  324.0
xRect:  144.78
yRect:  186.9
imageRect:  (144.78, 186.9, 15.0, 15.0)
```

[image: Graph on third load]

---

Edit 1:

I've been playing around with the auto constraints. I ended up removing them completely and on load it appears like the dot is appearing in the correct location:

[image]
(Note: This image is the same size as the others.)

However, because there's no constraints, the image is in the wrong size/location.

It appears theres funky stuff happening with the frame of the imageView when loading. And it doesn't reset until the view is reloaded a few seconds after being awoken from the nib.

---

Edit 2:

Further exploration of the edges of the imageView's bounds on load:

[image]

After reloading twice a few seconds after being awoken:

[image]

It appears the the constraints are not loading correctly. And they don't get fixed until the cell is reloaded.

---

Edit 3:

It appears that this issue **only** happens when the cell is a **displayed** cell on load.

Edit: The plot displays accurately when the cell with the graph isn't on screen when the viewController loads. However, if you refresh the cell, the issue occurs on the first reload, and is fixed on all following reload.

---

Edit 4: Added the code to plot the point thats based on point in relation to the bounds of the imageView.

```
@IBOutlet weak var graphImageView: UIImageView!
   var maxX: CGFloat?
   var maxY: CGFloat?
   
   var xData = 0.0
   var yData = 0.0
   
   // X:
   let xGood = 0.75..<6.5
   // Y:
   let yGood = 0.1..<1.0

func configureCell(point: (silicaX: Double, aluminaY: Double), hideLabels: Bool) {
    xData = point.silicaX
    yData = point.aluminaY
    plotGraph()
}




func plotGraph() {
        // X:
        var xAdjust: CGFloat = 0.0
        var graphX: CGFloat = 0.0
        
        // Setup For Point:
        print("xData: ", xData)
        switch xData {
            
        case xGood:
            print("X: xGood")
            
            xAdjust = graphImageView.bounds.maxX / (6.0/(0.5)) // Account for missing 0.5 not diplayed (6/.5)\
            
            let xTick = graphImageView.bounds.maxX / 6
            graphX = xTick * CGFloat(xData) - xAdjust
            
        default:
            print("X: Default ---")
        }
        
        // Y:
        var yAdjust: CGFloat = 0.0
        var graphY: CGFloat = 0.0
        let aluminaAdjust = CGFloat(yData * 10)
        
        switch yData {
            
        case yGood:
            print("Y: yGood")
            yAdjust = graphImageView.bounds.maxY / (1 / 0.05) // Account for missing 0.05 not diplayed
            
            let yTick = (graphImageView.bounds.maxY / 10)
            
            graphY = graphImageView.bounds.maxY - (yTick * aluminaAdjust) + yAdjust // Subtract?
            
        default:
            print("Y: Default ---")
        }
        // Setup Dot:
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        
        // Image Rect:
        var imageRectSize: CGFloat = 30
        var xRect: CGFloat = 0.0
        var yRect: CGFloat = 0.0
        
        // Display Dot:
        switch (xData, yData) {
            
        // Good:
        case (xGood, yGood):
            print("(xGood, yGood):")
            imageRectSize = 15
            imageView.backgroundColor = .label
            
            xRect = graphX - (imageRectSize / 2)
            yRect = graphY - (imageRectSize / 2)
            
        // Error:
        default:
            print("Default: (point.silicaX, point.aluminaY) ---")
        }
        
        // Set Dot Position:
        let imageRect = CGRect(x: xRect, y: yRect, width: imageRectSize, height: imageRectSize)
        
        // Set Dot Properties:
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageRectSize / 2
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        
        // Add Dot To View:
        imageView.frame = imageRect
        graphImageView.addSubview(imageView)
    }
```

---

Edit 5: Added Image of constraints

[image]

---

Edit 6:

I added the following code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        switch indexPath {
        case [sectionAnalysis, rowChart]:
            let graphCell = cell as! GraphTableViewCell
            graphCell.plotGraph()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

### It's seemed to fix the issue with the plotting (And bounds of the UIImageView) when reloading. So now the issue seems to be limited to only when the cell is on screen when the viewController loads.

Comment: Likely, you're doing your coordinate calculations before auto-layout has finished its work. Try to strip down your code to a [mre] to get help.

Comment: Hey Don, Thanks for the reply. That gives me something to look into. But I'm not sure thats the issue. The "Code" shown isn't code. It's print statements of various aspects the graph showing the plotting should be correct even though the sizes are changing. - As such I'm not sure how I could ask this question with less code than no code.

Comment: Hey @DonMag, it appears that auto layout itself isn't working correctly. I've added a few more images that show the bounds of the frame at load.

Comment: Can you show the actual code @StonedStudio ?  I believe DonMag was just asking for that, the minimal related code that can be referenced if some one wants to help you with the issue.

Comment: @KaylaGalway Sure. Give me a few minutes. I've been fussing with it and for some reason and wont even run without crashing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is code I needed to run the function again after the cell finished its setup. Or basically setting up all the layouts.

```
 override func layoutSubviews() {
       super.layoutSubviews()
        plotGraph()
    }
```